# Ajax form in knockout.js setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am new to Ajax and knockout and working on top of an existing code, so any kind of help would be appreciated.

What I have to do is, I have to make the below function work in a knockout setting. The following code is working, but I am having a problem making it work in a page that uses knock-out setting.

```
<div data-bind="style: { display: isShortlisted() === false ? 'inline-block' : 'none'}">
    <form id="shortlistForm" action="@MVC.GetLocalUrl(MVC.HireOrgJobApplication.AjaxShortlist(Model.Application))" method="post" style="display:inline;">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
           <input type="hidden" name="ApplicationKey" value="@Model.Application.ApplicationKey" />
               <button type="submit" class="btn-act jui-tooltip" title="Shortlist">
                   <i class="fa fa-2x fa-star"></i>
               </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

So it's basically a button that "shortlists" and applicant. I think it is trying to post "@Model.Application.ApplicationKey" to "ajax-shortlist" link according to the "Network" console on Google Chrome, if I check the working version of this code. (screenshot attached)

[image]

So the screenshot shows that the application key is added to the ajax-shortlist page and made it "shortlisted".

When I just copy-paste code into the page with knockout setting, it gives me an error as follows:

[image]

I know the question lacks a lot of information, but I can provide more information if you ask for it. I just don't know how to approach it.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I can add bit more information. So what I am trying to do is, if I click the button, it should not only post the information to the ajax-shortlist but also should change the icon.

```
<div data-bind="style: { display: isShortlisted() === true ? 'inline-block' : 'none'}">
  <form id="unshortlistForm" action="@MVC.GetLocalUrl(MVC.HireOrgJobApplication.AjaxUnshortlist(Model.Application))" method="post" style="display: inline;">
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="hidden" name="ApplicationKey" value="@Model.Application.ApplicationKey" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn-act-active jui-tooltip" title="Remove from shortlist">
        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-star" style="color:#f3b700;"></i>
      </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

But this only works when I refresh it. It is supposed to automatically change to this button when I click the shortlist button. I am assuming that it's because we cannot render ajax forms on a doc.ready setting. So what I basically need is, I want the ajax to work after the knockout is generated.

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raising an Ajax event after knockout rendering is done? (explained with screenshots)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610454/raising-an-ajax-event-after-knockout-rendering-is-done-explained-with-screensh)

Comment: One thing to remember with ASP.Net MVC and knockoutjs is where the processing work is done.  ASP.Net MVC is server based and knockoutjs is client based.